# How to create a view with TouchDown and TouchUp events in Xamarin.Forms with ScnViewGestures.Forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

ScnViewGestures.Forms is a Nuget package that allows to set up any subview in a page with custom touch handlers. However, from reading its sparce docu on github [1](https://github.com/ScienceSoft-Inc/ViewGestures) it is not easy to figure out how to use it. So how can you create a custom view with TouchDown and TouchUp event handlers in Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working code sample. Don't forget to install the nuget package ScnViewGestures.Forms and initialize it like this:

iOS (in AppDelegate.cs):

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init ();
ViewGesturesRenderer.Init();
```

Android:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
ViewGesturesRenderer.Init();
```

WinPhone:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init ();
ViewGesturesRenderer.Init();
```

Then you can create custom views like this little button, that handles down and up events separately, which the Xamarin.Forms standard button is unable to do.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using ScnViewGestures.Plugin.Forms;

namespace ViewGesturesExample {
    public partial class ButtonView : ContentView
    {
        public ButtonView ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            Content = _gestures = new ViewGestures () {
                HorizontalOptions = new LayoutOptions(LayoutAlignment.Fill, true),
                VerticalOptions = new LayoutOptions(LayoutAlignment.Fill, true),
            };
            _gestures.Content=_button=new Label () {
                HorizontalOptions = new LayoutOptions(LayoutAlignment.Fill, true),
                VerticalOptions = new LayoutOptions(LayoutAlignment.Fill, true),
                XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                YAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
            };
            _gestures.TouchBegan += OnTouchDown;
            _gestures.TouchEnded += OnTouchUp;          
            // here you have more events like 
            //Tap;
            //SwipeLeft;
            //SwipeRight;
            //SwipeUp;
            //SwipeDown.
        }

            Label _button;
            ViewGestures _gestures;

            private void OnTouchDown(object sender, EventArgs args) {

            }

            private void OnTouchUp(object sender, EventArgs args) {

            }
        }

}
```

Comment: For all these who looking for the source code of the used pluign: https://github.com/ScienceSoft-Inc/ViewGestures